# Russian visa goes in effect at what time?

Tags: visas, russia, timezones

My visa comes into effect on the 8th but does that mean I will be able to cross the Russian border at 00 in the Russian territory that I want to cross, or 00 in the foreign territory I come from?

Comment: I have zero insight into Russian rules and practice but I would guess it's the time at the border checkpoint. Anything else would be much more complex to check and enforce and also make Russian visas dependent on foreign countries' decisions. What scenario do you have in mind? Showing up in the morning and being turned down because it's not the 8th in your country yet? Being exactly after midnight at the border between Poland and Kaliningrad? Boarding a plane when your visa is not valid yet? Didn't you submit an itinerary/travel confirmation when applying for the visa?

Comment: Glad it helped but it's not an answer, just a comment because I don't really know, I am just guessing ;-) Maybe someone who speaks Russian, actually know the rules or has some personal experience will submit an answer.

Comment: out of interest what time are you arriving and from what country?

Answer (score 2):

It'll be at the border.  Russia won't care what time it is in another country for the purposes of a visa for *Russia*.

So if you're entering Russia on the 8th, and it's the 8th in Russia, then you can come in.  It's that simple :)

edit: thinking back, I've seen them be strict on the hours, when leaving Russia. Although we got on the train to Mongolia, at say, 8pm on the 8th, we didn't hit the border until say, 4am on the 9th, so the poor Canadian in our carriage who hadn't planned it had a visa that expired on the 8th.  Worth taking into consideration that it takes several hours to reach some borders, depending on where you depart.